# How to calculate the center point of an arc?

Tags: math, canvas, graphics, drawing, android-canvas

I have a CustomPieView which is made of several pie slices. I have to draw something in the middle of every pie section.

//Inside Activity's onCreate Method

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

```
    int size = 400;
    int bgColor = 0xffa11b1;
    ViewPieChart piechart = (ViewPieChart) findViewById(R.id.pieChartView);
    piechart.setCallBack(this);
    piechart.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(size, size));
    piechart.setGeometry(size, size, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2130837504);
    piechart.setSkinparams(bgColor);
    piechart.setData(piedata, maxCount);
    piechart.invalidate();
```

}

//CustomPieView extends View

```
public void setGeometry(int width, int height, int gapleft, int gapright, int gaptop, int gapbottom, int overlayid) {

    mWidth = width;
    mHeight = height;
    mGapleft = gapleft;
    mGapright = gapright;
    mGapBottm = gapbottom;
    mGapTop = gaptop;
}
```

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

```
    canvas.drawColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    mBagpaints.setAntiAlias(true);
    mBagpaints.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mBagpaints.setColor(0x88FF0000);
    mBagpaints.setStrokeWidth(0.0f);
    mLinePaints.setAntiAlias(true);
    mLinePaints.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    mLinePaints.setStrokeWidth(3.0f);
    mLinePaints.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);       
    sLinePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    sLinePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    sLinePaint.setStrokeWidth(3.0f);
    sLinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    RectF mOvals = new RectF(mGapleft, mGapTop, mWidth - mGapright, mHeight
            - mGapBottm);
    mStart = START_INC;
    PieDetailsItem item;
    for (int i = 0; i < mdataArray.size(); i++) {
        item = (PieDetailsItem) mdataArray.get(i);
        mBagpaints.setColor(item.color);
        mSweep = (float) 360* ((float) item.count / (float) mMaxConnection);
        canvas.drawArc(mOvals, mStart, mSweep, true, mBagpaints);
        canvas.drawArc(mOvals, mStart, mSweep, true, mLinePaints);
```

//          The function below is setting the global vars 
            cSegX, cSegY to the center of the segment. Not              Working!!

```
        calculateMidPointOfPieSegment(mSweep);
        canvas.drawPoint(cSegX, cSegY, sLinePaint);
        mStart = mStart + mSweep;
    }
    mState = IS_DRAW;
    callBack.onDrawFinished(null);
}

private float calculateRadius(){
float width = mWidth/2;
float height = mHeight/2;
    if(width < height){
        return width;
    }else{
        return height;
    }
}

private void calculateMidPointOfPieSegment(float sweepAngle){
    cSegX = (float)((calculateRadius()/2)*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(sweepAngle/2))+(mWidth/2));
    cSegY = (float)((calculateRadius()/2)*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(sweepAngle/2))+(mHeight/2));
}
```

Just see the dots in the image below, it has to be in the center of every arc.
[Screenshot](http://www.mediafire.com/?74dhiz6qw6bid0f)

[Ref.](http://www.rqna.net/qna/mryzsz-how-to-display-text-dynamically-on-pie-chart-in-android.html)

Complete [Source](http://www.mediafire.com/?fdob9ssz5l9oaw3)

Comment: What do you mean by the center of every arc? As in, for each pie slice shape, you want to put a dot in the middle of the curved outer edge? Or you want it to be equidistant from the tip of the slice to the rounded edge, and from the two sides?

Comment: I meant center point of the pie slice shape.

Comment: Fair. I'm a bit hung over, and I don't feel like looking through your source code looking for the origins of all the variables you used. But I'll help you solve the problem. I just need to know what data you have handy to work with. Do you have the two angles or degrees of the circle that make up the pie slice? Can you get them? Also, from the x and y, I'm assuming you're working on a grid, is the center of the circle at (0,0)? If not, what is it at?

Comment: I'm using [canvas.drawArc()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawArc(android.graphics.RectF, float, float, boolean, android.graphics.Paint)) method.

For this, I have to pass a 
startAngle: Starting angle (in degrees) where the arc begins
sweepAngle: Sweep angle (in degrees) measured clockwise

"is the center of the circle at (0,0)". No, it's centered at the oval's center(1st param of drawArc func.), which is been set in the lines that I've mentioned above

int size = 400;
piechart.setGeometry(size, size, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2130837504);

Comment: Did you see my answer/did it solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Let me know if this clears it up. This is the basic logic you want to implement.

```
    //rimPoint = (rX, rY)
    //centerPoint = (cX,cY)
    //theta is the angle of the the midpoint measured anticlockwise from the x axis, 
    //or the average of the two angles making up the slice(measured anticlockwise from 
    //the x axis)
    private void calculateMidPointOfPieSegment(cX,cY, theta)
    {
       float rX = cX + calculateRadius()*(cos(theta))
       float rY = cY + calculateRadius()*(sin(theta))

       cSegX = (rX+cX)/2;
       cCegY = (rY+cY)/2;
    }
```

If theta isn't in radians, sub it out for theta*Math.PI/180